# Mendeley 2.102.0 not autogenerating citation keys

Tags: bibliographies, mendeley

Mendeley does not always auto generate citation keys for entries. It seems to consistently miss webpages and articles it sometimes does and sometimes doesn't. This is very annoying because it stops latex referencing from working.

This question has been answered [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461971/mendeley-not-generating-citation-key-on-desktop-version) but the instructions are out of date since they say go to tools -> options but I have no options option in tools.

I am using Mendeley 2.102.0, can anyone help me solve the problem in this version of the GUI or what version I need?